# Use filemanager to select directory instead of file?

Tags: python, scripting, export

I want my export operator to open the normal file selector but instead of asking for a specific file I want it to ask for a directory. The reason for this is that both my model and the textures should be stored in a directory tree and I want to user to select the root. For example the model file "somemodel.ext" links to the textures "tex1.png" and "tex2.png" the resulting file structure should look like this:

```
RootFolder
+--textures
   +--somemodel
      + tex1.png
      + tex2.png
+--models
   + somemodel.ext
```

and I want to user to select the RootFolder in the export fileselect.

Comment: Using savePath = bpy.path.abspath('//' + folderName + '/')     is working well for me.  The textures I'm baking are going into the specified folder which is in the same directory as the .blend.  I'll post a more complete code example if no one with more experience shows up with a better solution by tomorrow.

Comment: I know how to get a folder path but I want the filepicker (the thing that opens when you do Save As... for example) to notice that. And I surely don't want to export the files to a fixed location. But don't mind to post your code, anyway. If you want to discuss this come into the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

Comment: there are a couple Cycles bake Addons that have file selector dialogues.  You could dig up one of those for reference.

Answer (score 8):

The most compact solution that I found uses the method `WindowsManager.fileselect_add()` in `invoke()`, and doesn't use the Helpers.
The documentation of `fileselect_add` says:

*Opens a file selector with an operator. The string properties ‘filepath’, ‘filename’, ‘directory’ and a ‘files’ collection are assigned when present in the operator*

Actually, you need to specify *only* a `directory` StringProperty in your operator. In so doing, the possibility to select the name of the file will disappear.

Also, to show only folders by default you can add a property `filter_folder = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True, options={'HIDDEN'})`.

Since v2.80, declaring string/bool properties requires using the colon `:` sign instead of equal `=`.

### Full example, tested on Blender 3.6.0:

```py
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy.types import Operator

class SelectDirExample(Operator):

    """Create render for all chracters"""
    bl_idname = "example.select_dir"
    bl_label = "Dir Selection Example Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    # Define this to tell 'fileselect_add' that we want a directoy
    directory: StringProperty(
        name="Outdir Path",
        description="Where I will save my stuff"
        # subtype='DIR_PATH' is not needed to specify the selection mode.
        # But this will be anyway a directory path.
        )

    # Filters folders
    filter_folder: BoolProperty(
        default=True,
        options={"HIDDEN"}
        )

    def execute(self, context):

        print("Selected dir: '" + self.directory + "'")

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        # Open browser, take reference to 'self' read the path to selected
        # file, put path in predetermined self fields.
        # See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        # Tells Blender to hang on for the slow user input
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectDirExample)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SelectDirExample)


#
# Invoke register if started from editor
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    # OPTIONAL - test run
    bpy.ops.example.select_dir('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

### Full example, tested on Blender 2.79:

```py
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy.types import Operator

class SelectDirExample(bpy.types.Operator):

    """Create render for all chracters"""
    bl_idname = "example.select_dir"
    bl_label = "Dir Selection Example Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    # Define this to tell 'fileselect_add' that we want a directoy
    directory = StringProperty(
        name="Outdir Path",
        description="Where I will save my stuff"
        # subtype='DIR_PATH' is not needed to specify the selection mode.
        # But this will be anyway a directory path.
        )

    # Filters folders
    filter_folder = BoolProperty(
        default=True,
        options={"HIDDEN"}
        )

    def execute(self, context):

        print("Selected dir: '" + self.directory + "'")

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        # Open browser, take reference to 'self' read the path to selected
        # file, put path in predetermined self fields.
        # See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        # Tells Blender to hang on for the slow user input
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectDirExample)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SelectDirExample)


#
# Invoke register if started from editor
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    # OPTIONAL - test run
    bpy.ops.example.select_dir('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

You can test the manual file selection by hitting SPACE on a 3D view and searching for `Dir Selection Example Operator`.

Differently, when executed from Python code you can specify the directory on your own: `bpy.ops.demo.select_dir_example(directory='/tmp')`

Comment: I consider this the better answer now. Btw to show only folders by default you can add a property `filter_folder = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True, options={'HIDDEN'})`. For further reference on options you can set via properties consult [the source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_file/filesel.c$94).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in 2.82

Comment: In Blender 2.8 and newer use the annotation syntax to define properties. Replace the equal sign (=) with a colon (:) like: `directory: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Directory", options={"HIDDEN"})` resp. `filter_folder: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True, options={"HIDDEN"})`

Comment: Edited the answer to include the above comments 

Answer (score 7):

I presume the main question here is selecting a root directory with the FileSelector.

bpy_extras.io_utils.ExportHelper includes [FileSelectParams](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FileSelectParams.html), which when set give the desired functionality.

The first attribute to be set is:
`use_filter_folder = True`
This will filter anything that is not a folder to the user. This also has the added advantage that the path your script gets back is folder.

You also need to set a file extension type, even though it is not used. It will cause an error on execution. Possible bug?
`filename_ext = "."`

This is based on an for general file import - [How do I get the filepath when I import a file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14572/how-do-i-get-the-filepath-when-i-import-a-file/14574#14574)

Full sample

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
    
import os.path

class ExportOperator(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Operator for setting a directory path."""

    #: Name of function for calling the nif export operator.
    bl_idname = "export_scene.folder"

    #: How the nif import operator is labelled in the user interface.
    bl_label = "Export to folder"

    filename_ext = "."
    use_filter_folder = True

    def execute(self, context):
        userpath = self.properties.filepath
        if not os.path.isdir(userpath):
            msg = "Please select a directory not a file\n" + userpath
            self.report({'WARNING'}, msg)

        #Insert the desired logic here to write to the directory.

        return{'FINISHED'}

def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        ExportOperator.bl_idname, text="Export Scene to folder")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.remove(menu_func_import)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: thanks for pointing the possible bug out. Though appreciating the effort, this script doesn't LIMIT the user to only select directories. I could of course just ignore the filename the user gives it (something like "model1") but then I would have to deal with all those asking what the filename is, etc.

Comment: If the user does decide to enter in a path that is not a directory, then just sanitise with ```os.path.isdir(file_path)```. You can only be so defensive.

Comment: You can actually, instead of using ExportHelper, use your own filepath attribute defined as `filepath = StringProperty(type='DIR_PATH')`.

Comment: I think it should be StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')