# How to add images from selected folder via Python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

## In my Panel class I use:

```
col.prop(context.scene, 'path')
```

## I also have:

```
def register():
bpy.utils.register_class(PBRGROUP)
bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
bpy.types.Scene.path = bpy.props.StringProperty \
  (
  name = "Folder with textures",
  default = "",
  description = "Select folder with images to import",
  subtype = 'DIR_PATH'
  )   


def unregister():
bpy.utils.unregister_class(PBRGROUP)
bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
del bpy.types.Scene.path
```

## The above gives me:

[image]

How to add all images from selected folder to my .blend file?

I know how to create a button, but I don't know how to add files from directory.

Comment: Related: [How to create a Folder Dialog](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/how-to-create-a-folder-dialog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an adapted version of [this nice generator](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.co.il/2015/06/a-png-iterator-generator-from-given.html) to your code to find all images in a given folder (such as the ones you keep in your Scene.path property):

```
import bpy, os
def path_iterator(folder_path):
    for fp in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if fp.endswith( tuple( bpy.path.extensions_image ) ):
            yield fp
```

Then you can iterate over the images and do whatever you want with them, for instance to add them to the list of images blender can use for textures and other purposes:

```
for imgPath in path_iterator( bpy.context.scene.path ):
    fullPath = os.path.join( bpy.context.scene.path, imgPath )
    bpy.ops.image.open( filepath = fullPath )
```

Comment: you can use `fp.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.tif', '.hdr'))` , feed it a tuple.

Comment: Nice,didn't know that.

Comment: @TLousky  bpy.path.extesions_image is a set of all image formats supported (by extension)

Comment: @batFINGER awesome, will update the script accordingly.

Comment: To go OTT maybe path_iterator returned a  files collection consistent with multi flie operators.  bpy.ops.image.open(directory=fp, files=path_image_files(fp))

Comment: That could be useful (especially for this specific use), though might be a bit less versatile. No time today for the research involved though (collection format).

Comment: My image's name is texnormal.png. I want to import this image by extension (.png) and "normal" text in its name. I wrote this code, but it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?  if fp.endswith(supported_file_types) and fp[-10:] in ['normal']:

Comment: if fp = "texnormal.png", then fp[-10:] = "normal.png". So the conditional fp[-10:] in ['normal'] will result with a False value (and the brackets [] shouldn't be there since you're testing for substrings within strings). You can reverse it to **'normal' in fp[-10:]** which will work, or to **fn[-10:-4] == 'normal'**.

Comment: I have one more question. I created a text box:         **box.prop(context.scene, "normal_map_string")** and how to replace _'normal'_ by user defined text in this line  **'normal' in fp[-10:]**?

Comment: I wrote this: **if fp.endswith(supported_file_types) and  "context.scene.normal_map_string" in fp[-10:]:** but it's not working

Comment: I found the solution. **(bpy.context.scene.normal_map_string) in fp[-10:])** works perfectly.