# Python script creating a sub-folder?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, file-browser

After a couple of suggestions which I couldn't make work, I've decided to simplify my goal and question.

My original script would generate the images properly but I was limited to having it just spit them out into w/e folder the .blend file is in.

```
# write image
image.filepath_raw = "//BaseRough.png"
image.file_format = 'PNG'
image.save()
```

I've been trying to tell it to make a new folder, direct to that, and generate the images there, but it's not working.

This line:

```
bpy.ops.file.directory_new(directory='//textures/', open=False, confirm=True)
```

Yields the error: `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.file.directory_new.poll() failed, context is incorrect`

I'm not sure how to give it context.

I also need it to be able to read the files and assign them to the appropriate nodes, though I assume changing the load path accordingly will do that.

```
img = bpy.data.images.load("//BaseRough.png", check_existing=True)
to:
img = bpy.data.images.load("//textures/BaseRough.png", check_existing=True)
```

**Update**

I've been scouring the internet looking for bits of code for this, as well as any kind of explanation how the `os.` system works in blender, and it led me eventually back around to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168687/blender-python-how-to-create-path-and-folder-structure-from-within-blender).

I still have no idea how the window system works, but the code section on the bottom does actually work if I give it a file path to use.

Now my question is, how do I get it to use the local file's directory and add a folder to that?

```
os.getcwd()
'/home/monty'

# changed to:

os.getcwd()
'//'
```

Doesn't do anything at all. But there must be a way to define the path in a way it can see. If I can get that to work that will be good enough for now.

Someday I definitely do want to get the file window option to do the job, but clearly I'm not at that level yet.

**Update**

More digging has led me to [this question,](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173524/how-can-i-append-an-object-from-an-external-blender-file-using-a-relative-path-w) which inspired me to figure out this:

```
filepath = "//"
abs_filepath = bpy.path.abspath(filepath) # returns the absolute path
os.mkdir(str(abs_filepath+"textures"))
```

I'm so close I can taste it. Now I just need to write up a check for this so it's doesn't spit out `FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'textures'`

Comment: Hello ! In the script editor you should look into Templates > Python > Operator File Import

Comment: I had a poke around in that template you mentioned, it hasn't helped me yet. See my update for the details.

Comment: If your question is how to get the path that was picked by fileselect_add, you read `self.filepath` in the execute() function. Why are you creating a text object and then running it vs just calling a function (to which you could pass the path)?

Comment: I'm not creating a text object, it's just the only template I could find. Nobody else seems to want to do what I'm trying to do. I have a button on a menu that runs a script. That script makes 12 image files and assigns them to image nodes. At present, it just makes them in the directory with the active .blend file. I'm trying to add a way to make/choose a specific folder instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think this is the simplest possible way to make this happen, so here I go.

```
filepath = "//" # this line finds where the current .blend file is relative to itself
abs_filepath = bpy.path.abspath(filepath) # returns the absolute path
if not os.path.isdir(str(abs_filepath+"textures")): # checks whether the directory exists
    os.mkdir(str(abs_filepath+"textures")) # if it does not yet exist, makes it
# if it does exist, moves on to the rest of the script
```

After the above, the image generator can use `//textures/imgname.png` as both the destination, and to call the image and load it for use.

If anyone has a recommendation for the windowed file path chooser, and **an explanation of how their recommendation works,** I'd still like to try getting to that level.