# Set maximum width for an operator's button in UI?

Tags: python, scripting

How can I set a width maximum or fixed value for a button?

I have an UI looking like this:
[image]

The text field would be full path of a file and the 'Set' button is openning a dialog box. How can I go about increasing the text field's width and reducing the button's width? 
Thanks
Kaveh

Comment: FYI: When using a `StringProperty` set to `FILE_PATH`, a button (to call the file browser) is going to be added automatically ->  [How to create a Folder Dialog?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26906/31447). This also would make it consistent with the rest of the UI so the question is: Do you really want to have an extra extra operator to call that dialog?

Comment: Great!This actually makes it so much easier and the code much simpler. 
In gerneral though is there a way, other than row and column definition to control the size of button?

Comment: There is split and flow: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html#user-interface-layout Also have a look into the python templates that comes with blender. Can we close this one as a duplicate or the linked question?

Comment: sure. thanks a lot!