# How can I get the full path of the selected file from the file explorer?

Tags: python, scripting, properties, file-browser

I have tried in several ways and the only one that worked for me was through a modal that extends from `ImportHelper`, however I would like to do everything from the main panel:

[image]

```
import bpy 
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "Test"
    bl_label = "Test File"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = 'View'
 
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        layout.prop(scene, 'file_')
        
def showPath(self, context):
    print("filepath: ", bpy.context.scene.file_)# return only //x_bot.json 
    print("self.filepath", self.filepath)# return error
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.file_ = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name= "File", 
        subtype='FILE_PATH', 
        update=showPath
    )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainPanel)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`bpy.path.abspath()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.path.html#bpy.path.abspath)

> Returns the absolute path relative to the current blend file using the “//” prefix.

TLDR; Just call [`bpy.path.abspath(your_path)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.path.html#bpy.path.abspath) to get the *absolute path* representation.

---

There is no reason to display the *absolute path* nor convert it because the user can set it to *absolute* or *relative* in the *File Browser* (<kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Also notice: there are several naming conventions like adding a [separator to the name of your panel class](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons#Naming) or using lowercase names for functions and variables ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)):

```
import bpy

class CATEGORY_PT_CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene

        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(scn, "my_path", text="")

        # Print the absolute and relative path to the console
        print ("REL:", scn.my_path)
        print ("ABS:", bpy.path.abspath(scn.my_path))


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CATEGORY_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_path = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="File", subtype='FILE_PATH')

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CATEGORY_PT_CustomPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Related**

- [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57306/31447)
- [How to create a Folder Dialog?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26898/31447)