# Create a folder dialog box for an addon (2.91)

Tags: python, scripting, export, add-on

I'm trying to add a folder dialog box in the add-on I'm working on.
I managed to add a button that opens a folder dialog and setup the path, but I'd like to be able to see that path rather than just printing it in the console.

Something like that :

[image: Folder Dialog Box]

I'm currently using an operator and I found out that I need to use a Property, here's what I tried :

```
class project_path(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
path: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype="DIR_PATH")
```

and then tried to call it in my Panel with :

```
class PT_Panel(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type ="UI"
    bl_label = "Operations"
    bl_category = "Tools"

    def draw(self, context):

        layout = self.layout

        sce = context.scene

        box = layout.box()
        box.label( text = "Project Path")

        row = box.row()
        row.prop(sce.project_path,"path",text='Project Path')
```

But then I got that error :

```
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'project_path'
```

Can't find any help on that, I guess I'm not using the correct attribute, but I've tried a bunch of different things without success, am I not supposed to use the class as an attribute ?

I found [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/how-to-create-a-folder-dialog) that is relevant, but it's also not explaining where the attribute is taken from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get it to work

Import :

> ```
> from bpy.props import PointerProperty
> ```

In your PT_Panel class:

> ```
> ProjPath = context.scene.proj_path
> row.prop(ProjPath, "path", text='Project Path')
> ```

While registering:

> ```
> classes = [project_path, PT_Panel]
>
> def register():
>
>     for cls in classes :
>         bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
>         bpy.types.Scene.proj_path= PointerProperty(type= project_path)
>
>
> def unregister():
>
>     for cls in classes :
>         bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
>         del bpy.types.Scene.proj_path
>
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     register()
> ```

If you want to save it permanently then use [AddonPrefrences](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/add-on-preferences-panel/)

And try to improve your naming skills :

> 1. Darkfall - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i12oOBI3E28
> 2. Red-K Production- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1gU50MKulw

Comment: Thanks for the help on that, being using python for a week or so and trying to do an add-on for like 2 days so still a lot to learn. Your solution works, I had to modify the identation a bit for the pointerproperty registration and unregister but it works ! I will definitely get a look at the naming convention videos you gave me. Thank you so much for your help ! –