# How to make search folder script in add-on preference?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

How to make search folder script in add-on preference? I want to make a button to search a folder in add-on preference that can search resource files like the Extreme PBR add-on.
[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome! Consider that the bare minimum here is to show some effort towards your goal. I'd recommend always add the current state of your code to your question, makes it way easier to give an answer. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The example given is just a regular [`StringProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty) added to the [`AddonPreferences`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html). Notice that the `subtype` of the [`StringProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty) is set to `DIR_PATH`:

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, AddonPreferences
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty

class ExampleAddonPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__

    filepath: StringProperty(
        name="Example File Path",
        subtype='DIR_PATH')

    number: IntProperty(
        name="Example Number",
        default=4)

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text="This is a preferences view for our add-on")
        self.layout.prop(self, "filepath")
        self.layout.prop(self, "number")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExampleAddonPreferences)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExampleAddonPreferences)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Further reading**

- [`AddonPreferences` in the Docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html)
- [How to create a Folder Dialog?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/how-to-create-a-folder-dialog/)
- [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui/)