# How to use the File Browser's (with ImportHelper) execute function?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, node-editor, file-browser

I now have the file browser, and I've found out how to load the texture into the node but not from the file browser. I have to type the file path in manually, and I had to put it in a different class that was activated with a bool... so, **how can I activate the file browser instead?**

[image]

#### code

```
import bpy
import os
from bpy.types import (Menu, PropertyGroup)
from bpy.props import (BoolProperty, FloatProperty, EnumProperty, StringProperty)
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper

def update_texture(self, context):
    path = self.screen_texture.value
    img = bpy.data.images.load(filepath = path)

    nt = bpy.data.materials['Screen'].node_tree
    n = nt.nodes["screen_texture"].image = img

class IgnitProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    screen_path = StringProperty(
       name="Browse Image:",
       description="Loads the texture for the screen",
       maxlen= 1024,
       subtype='FILE_PATH',
       update=update_texture
   )

class IdentifierFileSelector(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_label = "File Browser"
    bl_idname = "macbook_controller.identifier_file_selector"

    def execute(self, context):
        fdir = self.properties.filepath

        # Screen Texture


        return{'FINISHED'}

class IGLayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "MacBook Controller"
    bl_idname = "macbook_controller.macbook_controller"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Screen Texture
        layout.label(text = "Screen Texture:")
        layout.prop(scene.ignit_panel, "screen_path", text="")
```

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14572/how-do-i-get-the-filepath-when-i-import-a-file/14574#14574

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Folder Dialog?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/how-to-create-a-folder-dialog)

Comment: inside the execute function is where you could include the code that updates the node's  `.img` , or you could call a function from there and pass it the filepath.

Comment: Might be a good idea to split up your question in order to make it useful for others too.

Comment: @poor What would you suggest?

Comment: it is kind of an awkward question. being able to ask and answer the question relies on understanding several concepts. Not a bad question, just tricky to form it as a question that will benefit more readers.

Comment: @MatthewInglis In addition to zeffii's comment: Please consider that this site is not a personal support forum, it's is run by people who like to use blender and volunteer their time to help others. Try to abstract/recap/compress your questions as best you can instead of pasting your whole code in here and ask for a solution. This will help you to find the issue on your own and also will help future visitors. Also avoid asking multiple questions at once. 'How to create a folder dialog, import an image and using this for my material?' is simply too broad and may get down voted. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `ImportHelper` - a class that wraps the FileBrowser.

```
import os
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper

class IdentifierFileSelector(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "something.identifier_file_selector"
    bl_label = "some folder"

    def execute(self, context):
        fdir = self.properties.filepath

        # do something with fdir here  (fullpath)

        return{'FINISHED'}
```

#### bl_idname

- Should be lowercase.
- For your own sanity it's useful to make it consistent with the class name. If the class name is `XxxxxxYyyyZzzzzz` then a predictable  `bl_idname` would be `"xxxxx_yyyyy_zzzz"`
- The prefix (i called it "something" in the code above) is a way for you to create a namespace for your own operators. Each operator is found in `bpy.ops.*` therefor your operator would be found at `bpy.ops.something.identifier_file_selector`

---

In this scenario, the StringProperty isn't something you want to be typing into *ever*. The update function is a little overkill then. See that property as visual reference to show you which file you picked.

```
class IgnitProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    screen_path = StringProperty(description="Contains path to a texture")


class IdentifierFileSelector(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_label = "File Browser"
    bl_idname = "macbook_controller.identifier_file_selector"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Screen Texture
        img = bpy.data.images.load(filepath=self.properties.filepath)

        # update the node
        nt = bpy.data.materials['Screen'].node_tree
        n = nt.nodes["screen_texture"].image = img

        # also update this StringProperty so it reflects what you picked 
        context.scene.ignit_panel.screen_path = self.properties.filepath
        return{'FINISHED'}
```

your draw

```
scn = bpy.context.scene
row = layout.row()
row.prop(scn.ignit_panel, "screen_path")  # <-- just for display purposes
row.operator("macbook_controller.identifier_file_selector", text="", icon='FILE')
```

Comment: Do I need to have the bl_ things, I have them in another class, do they have to be in both?

Comment: Gee, you're the best! I'm not sure if this would mean much to you but when I finish this model I'm email it to you for free, just as a token of my appreciation! (seeing as though like half the code here is based off your code!)

Comment: We're all building on the shoulders of giants. What Blender _bpy_ lacks in documentation is made up for by its sheer amount of free open source add-on examples. (except you might have to wade through a tonne of code to find the nuggets of interest)