# How to import a STL file using the file browser?

Tags: python, scripting, import, geometry, file-format

I'm trying to import a stl file manually via python. My code below is pretty straight forward, but I'm struggling with the following line. I'm not sure about the syntax and format of the arguments:

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=???, files=???)
```

The current state of my operator:

```
import bpy

class FILE_OT_import_stl(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "file.import_model_stl"
    bl_label = "Import Model STL"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} # Must have REGISTER!   

    def execute(self, context):
        #my_filepath = 'K:/PQJ/Mold Generator/Blender test/'
        #filepath = '//898L-OutputModel-SLA[]_09'
        #print(filepath)
        all_files=[bpy.types.Scene.import_path]
        #print(file[0])
        bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=my_filepath, files=all_files)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class FILE_PANEL_PT_import_export(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Import/Export"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    # bl_context = "object" # object vs edit mode

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Import")
               
        layout.prop(context.scene, "import_path")
        row = layout.row()                
        row.operator("file.import_model_stl")

classes = (
    FILE_OT_import_stl,
    FILE_PANEL_PT_import_export
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.types.Scene.import_path = bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Import path', subtype='FILE_PATH')
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.import_path
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Q:** How to import a certain STL file using the file browser *(and add a custom material)*?

Comment: Do bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="your/path/here.stl").

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Also I am trying not to hard code the path but get it from my custom prop.

Comment: Depending on the situation you can just call `bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` or use `layout.operator("import_mesh.stl", text="Import STL", icon='FILE_NEW')` in your draw method if you want to import 1 file. Have a look into the *Operator File Import* template (magic is done by its ImportHelper class). Related: [How to use the File Browser's (with ImportHelper) execute function?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43828/31447), batch import example: [How to batch import Wavefront OBJ files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31825/31447). Do you'd like to import 1 or a few files?

Comment: It's just 1 file and it needs to be selected by mouse click. After import I need to do a few things to the object - otherwise I could just use the import in the menu

Comment: It is selected anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the built-in operator [`import_mesh.stl`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.import_mesh.html?highlight=mesh_stl#bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl) to your draw method of your panel which will open up the *File Browser* as usual and allows the user to select one `.stl` file:

[image]

```
import bpy

class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        #layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' #'INVOKE_AREA'
        layout.operator("import_mesh.stl", text="New", icon='FILE_NEW')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Related: [How to call a confirmation dialog box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73286/how-to-call-a-confirmation-dialog-box/73548#73548)

---

In case you want to **import and modify** the `.stl` object for whatever reason, have a look into the *Operator File Import* template (`operator_file_import.py`) that comes with Blender.

[image]

*Demo operator* based on the template, allows to import the file, print the object reference and assigns a new material to the incoming object in one go:

```
# ImportHelper is a helper class, defines filename and
# invoke() function which calls the file selector.
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.types import Operator

class ImportSomeData(Operator, ImportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "import_test.some_data"
    bl_label = "Import Some Stl File"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    # ImportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".stl"
    filter_glob: bpy.props.StringProperty(
                default="*.stl",
                options={'HIDDEN'})
                
    def execute(self, context):
        if self.filepath:
            bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=self.filepath)
            # Print the imported object reference
            print ("Imported object:", context.object)
            # Create a material
            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="STLMaterial")
            # Append the material to the last slot
            context.object.data.materials.append(mat)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Further reading:

- [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python)
- [Import multiple STL files and modify the incoming objects in one go?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212573/31447)

Comment: Yeah. The 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' works like a charm. But I need to change the name of the object right after import (and maybe a few other things). This only imports (like in the menu)

Comment: I have seen the template and it just says: "bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=self.filepath)". I can't find where "self.filepath" is set.

Comment: Comes from the `ImportHelper` class, see my demo code.